# Removing indent/newline before and after leftbar

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

Im writing a summary of my lectures and encountered a problem.
I would like to insert a vertical left bar near the important theorems I have to know.
What I found so far is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5cm,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{framed}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
    \nobreak
    \def\FrameCommand{{\vrule width 1pt} \hspace{3pt} }%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext
    \begin{leftbar}
    \blindtext
    \end{leftbar}
    \blindtext\\
\end{document}
```

I already set the thickness of the line to 1 px because it was too big for my liking.

Here an example: Just plain text[image]

Becomes indented and makes a newline before and after the leftbar:[image]


What should I do to remove the indents and the new lines?

Many thanks in advice for your answers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the indentation at the start of the `leftbar` environment you need to add a `\noindent` to the begin-code. (And an `\ignorespaces` to protect against the space following `}`). For the indentation after the environment you can use the `\@endparenv` kernel macro. The vertical spacing around the environment is controlled by the length `\OuterFrameSep`, which you can redefine to zero (but leave it some ability to stretch).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{framed}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
   \OuterFrameSep=0ex plus .8ex
   \def\FrameCommand{{\vrule width 1pt} \hspace{3pt} }%
   \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}
   \noindent\ignorespaces
  }{%
   \endMakeFramed
   \csname@endparenv\endcsname
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{leftbar}
\blindtext
\end{leftbar}
Some text here to show no indentation.
\begin{leftbar}
Other lorem ipsum stuff.
\end{leftbar}

Here you \emph{do} have an indentation because of the additional empty line.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Careful with the spaces: right now

```
\def\FrameCommand{{\vrule width 1pt} \hspace{3pt} }
```

gives you an horizontal space of `3pt` *plus*  two spaces: see

```
a{\vrule width 1pt} \hspace{3pt} b\par
a{\vrule width 1pt}\hspace{3pt} b\par
a{\vrule width 1pt}\hspace{3pt}b
```

[image]

I would get rid of the two spaces and increase the `3pt` to something you like.

Comment: Beat me by a minute. +1

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I was writing an email and I wanted to rephrase it a bit, but in the end I decided not to. That would've been the decisive minute `:-)`

Comment: I too was diverted.  My loss!

Comment: Many thanks for your speedy answer! Perfectly described and does exactly what I wanted. Have a nice day!